# ActionBarActivity getSupportActionBar().hide() throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-support-library, android-actionbar-compat

Call

```
 if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
     getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

or just:

```
getActionBar()
```

in android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity  I get such exception:

```
    ...
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplICS.hide(ActionBarImplICS.java:302)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplJB.hide(ActionBarImplJB.java:20)
    ...
```

**EDIT:**
it just happens when activity have Theme:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    </style>
```

note:

```
getSupportActionBar()
```

do not return null

Comment: can you post the whole class?

Comment: What do you have in `AppTheme`? This issue is reproduced only on post ICS devices and it doesn't happen for pre-ICS maybe?

Comment: AppTheme = Theme.AppCompat.Light. I am already edited question. I am also think it is ICS bug.

Comment: updated answer to reflect the ICS case. I wasn't paying attention in the first case on where do you get the NPE.

Comment: @Abi-: did you found what was the problem?

Comment: Not to the end. What I found I wrote in my answer

Answer (score 7):

meet the same problem ,but I use code to set fullscreen and noActionbar below instead of theme in xml:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.page_welcome);
    initViews();
}
```

this code runs well before ICS but crashs caused by NullPointException above ICS,After some experiments,I got the solution:**delete one line code which set no title as below:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.page_welcome);
    initViews();
}
```

Then it works well at all platforms. : )

Answer (score 2):

As I understand

```
if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
     getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

is no correct!
 Becouse `getSupportActionBar()` return not-null instance of 
([android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplICS](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarImplICS.java#39))

after that we can call hide function (`getSupportActionBar().hide();`)

but inside this function we will have NullPointerException because variable `mActionBar` inside
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplICS instance  == null
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarImplICS.java#302

As I understand inside  constructor of android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplICS

```
 mActionBar = activity.getActionBar();
```

return null, because our Activity does not have ActionBar via Theme

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

In short:
`<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>` 
may be used with `Activity` only, NOT `ActionBarActivity`

On the other hand,`getSupportActionBar().hide();`
may be used with `ActionBarActivity`

Answer (score 0):

Having `Theme.AppCompat.Light` both for pre-ICS and post-ICS will definitely cause issues. The way of doing this is to set a `MyTheme` in:

1. `values/styles.xml`. This will extend from `Theme.AppCompat.Light`. Ex: `<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">`
2. `values-v11/styles.xml`. This will extend from a `Holo` theme. Ex: `<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">`

In this way, Android knows what kind of theme to load based on runtime device host API.

Don't call `getActionBar()` once you extend from `ActionBarActivity`. On post-ICS devices this will run, but for lower API devices you will get a runtime `not supported method` Exception or something equivalent.

Comment: As you can see in code snippet 
`getSupportActionBar()`
 DO NOT returns null, otherwise NullPointerException was not at 302th line in android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplICS class

but your guess about Theme was in right way, it is only happens when:
`style name="MyTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>`