# Why getActionBar() getting null value in TabHost from Android?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar, android-tabactivity

I am trying to write a code in Android , to hide the Actionbar during scroll down event. I have a grid 10x50. So when i am scrolling down the action bar should hide. I am getting scroll state result in the Log Cat correctly so , whenever i am applying for getActionBar().hide , i am getting NullPointerException error.

**My Code :**

```
package com.example.complexdatepicker;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class MainActivity extends TabActivity 
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();


        TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Home");

        tab1.setIndicator("Home");
        Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
        tab1.setContent(photosIntent);

        tabHost.addTab(tab1);


}

 }
```

**Home.java**

```
package com.example.complexdatepicker;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.GridView;


public class Home extends ActionBarActivity 
{

ArrayList<String> abc;

TestGrid tg;

GridView gv;

int mLastFirstVisibleItem;

int mLastVisibleItemCount;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        abc = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0;i<500;i++)
        {

            abc.add(String.valueOf(i));

        }


        tg = new TestGrid(Home.this,Home.this,abc);

        gv.setAdapter(tg);

        getSupportActionBar().hide(); /// Getting Error at this point..


     /*         
        gv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                if (mLastFirstVisibleItem > firstVisibleItem) {
                    Log.e(getClass().toString(), "scrolling up");
                    getActionBar().show();
                } else if (mLastFirstVisibleItem < firstVisibleItem) {
                    Log.e(getClass().toString(), "scrolling down");
                    getActionBar().hide();

                } else if (mLastVisibleItemCount < visibleItemCount) {
                    Log.e(getClass().toString(), "scrolling down");
                    getActionBar().hide();
                } else if (mLastVisibleItemCount > visibleItemCount) {
                    Log.e(getClass().toString(), "scrolling up");
                    getActionBar().show();
                }
                mLastFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
                mLastVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;
            }

            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView listView, int scrollState) {
            }
        });

     */         

}

 }
```

**TestGrid.java**

```
package com.example.complexdatepicker;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TestGrid extends BaseAdapter
{

    private ArrayList<String> abc;

    private FragmentActivity activity;

    private Context context; 

    String text;

    int c = 0;

    int x = 0;

    SelectDateFragment newFragment;



    public TestGrid(FragmentActivity activity , Context cont,ArrayList<String> abc)
    {

        super();

        this.activity=activity;

        this.context = cont;

        this.abc = abc;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {

        return abc.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int in) 
    {       

        return abc.get(in);

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) 
    {

        return 0;

    }

    public class ViewHolder
    {

        public TextView txt;

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) 
    {

        final SharedPreferences pref = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("TestDate", 0);

        ViewHolder view;

        LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        if(arg1==null)
        {

            view = new ViewHolder();

            arg1 = inflator.inflate(R.layout.test_grid, null);

            view.txt = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.txt);

            arg1.setTag(view);

        }
        else
        {

            view = (ViewHolder) arg1.getTag();

        }





         View.OnClickListener alert = new OnClickListener() 
         {


                public void onClick(View v) 
                {


                        Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), abc.get(arg0)+" - Clicked ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();

                    Bundle args = new Bundle();

                    newFragment.setArguments(args);


                    newFragment.setOnDateSetListener(new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd)
                        {

                            String saved_date = pref.getString("SavedDate", null);

                            Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "SavedDate : "+saved_date,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 


                        }


                    });



                    newFragment.show(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");       

                }


         };



        view.txt.setOnClickListener(alert);






        text = String.valueOf(abc.get(arg0));

        view.txt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.txtbk);

        view.txt.setTextSize(18);

        view.txt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        view.txt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);    

        view.txt.setText(text);

        return arg1;

    }




    @SuppressLint({ "ValidFragment", "NewApi" })
    public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener 
    {


        private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener externalListener;

        public void setOnDateSetListener(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener)
        {
            this.externalListener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {


                final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

                int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);

                int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);


        }


        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd)
        {

            SharedPreferences pref = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("TestDate", 0);

            Editor et = pref.edit();

            et.putString("SavedDate", String.valueOf(dd+"/"+mm+"/"+yy));

            et.commit();

            Log.d("SavedDate : ", String.valueOf(dd+"/"+mm+"/"+yy));

            if(externalListener != null)


                externalListener.onDateSet(view, yy, mm, dd);




        }


        public void onFinishEditDialog(String inputText) 
        {



        }


    }


}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
   <manifest 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.example.complexdatepicker"
     android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="14"
      android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

  <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >

 <activity

        android:name="com.example.complexdatepicker.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

     <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.complexdatepicker.Home"
        android:label="@string/app_name" ></activity>

 </application>
```

**Style.xml**

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

     </resources>
```

**Error Image:**

[image]

**Error :**

```
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  activity ComponentInfo{com.example.complexdatepicker/com.example.complexdatepicker.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.complexdatepicker/com.example.complexdatepicker.Home}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.complexdatepicker/com.example.complexdatepicker.Home}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2054)
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:749)
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:240)
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at com.example.complexdatepicker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  ... 11 more  
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplICS.hide(ActionBarImplICS.java:289)
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at com.example.complexdatepicker.Home.onCreate(Home.java:50)
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
05-25 11:10:37.374: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  ... 21 more
```

These are all above codes and error details  , please let me know how can i use **getActionBar()** in **TabWidget**.

Please suggest me some good solution.

Comment: Your are getting the Exception at `tg = new TestGrid(Home.this,Home.this,abc);`. 
Could you show your TestGrid class?

Comment: I have edited my post , please let me know , if you have any solution...

Answer (score 7):

Your Home `Activity` must extend `ActionBarActivity` instead of `FragmentActivity` so you can call `getActionBar()` method.

`ActionBarActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`. Also, you should use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()` because the latest requires API level 11.

Also note that you need to import v4 support library to be able to call `getSupportActionBar()` and support v7 library to use `ActionBarActivity`.

Comment: Yes brother i am doing everything right in the app manifest but don't find any reason ... why i am getting this exception...

Comment: Try to clean your project and run it again, then.

Comment: I have edited my post ... why i am getting a red symbol in my project folder after adding the v7 libraries into my app ... so i am not able to run my app now....

Comment: I have cleaned my project but nothing changed ... still having red exclamation in my project folder... please let me know...

Comment: Is your v7-appcompat library project ok, with no errors? Did you check it as library?

Comment: When you go to your Project properties, are you importing the right library?

Comment: i think so ... i got v7 library from my sdk extras->android->support-v7->appcompat-> and i imported this project.. and i add this as library to my project....

Comment: In Eclipse, you have a View called Problems. Check that section to see if any message helps you.

Comment: No friend not finding any issue from Problems view ... what's actual issue ? please suggest me....

Comment: Try to clean your v7 library, and import it again.

Comment: Ahh now i get it ...in android-support-v7-appcompat folder there is no java file inside the src folder , so what can i do now... where do i get all the source java files....

Comment: No, it is supposed not to have any classes in src folder. Check if libs folder has the v4 and v7 jars. And check your project build target correctly.

Comment: Nope i tried a lot but nothing great i found ... please suggest me how can i overcome this problem...? can sherlock could be a good option...?

Comment: Well, Sherlock is also a library. Eventually, you'll have the same problem. Your problem is importing a library. Does not have to do with the library itself, I think. Did you tried to do the whole process again? Are you importing the library from the right directory?

Comment: Let's try another approach. Create a new Android project, and on the new Project wizard,set minimum sdk to 11, the click Next, then choose master/detail flow. That project will automatically import appcompat v7 library. Then try to import your new v7 library into your own project.

Comment: No friend same result ... i created new project with minimum sdk to 11 and done master/detail flow ... but still getting error in getActionBar().hide.... getting NullPointerException at this point...  i didn't add v7 library this time....

Comment: Yes, but for it to work, you got to add it as library. And what about the new project? Does it work? Does it have an actionbar?

Comment: One more thing, could you show your styles.xml file. So I can see which Theme you have on your application?

Comment: No friend getting NullPointerException at getActionBar().hide... nothing working at all....

Comment: yes sure i have edited my post , please go through my style.xml file

Comment: You have to change your Manifest.xml, in tag application, to android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat". This theme is in v7-appcompat library. You have to import it to your project. Compare with the project you just created and see why is the reason it works and your project not.

Comment: Yes i have added the Theme.AppCompat in the manifest but getting some new exception now... i have edited my post ... please go through my Errors ...

Comment: You mean you managed to import v7-appcompat in your project without errors? If not, try importing actionbarsherlock

Comment: Yes i managed to import v7 libraries without errors... but having exception still now....

Comment: Ok then. Did you try to check if getSupportActionBar() != null before you make the call?

Comment: Also, try to do some research, there are lots of cases like yours. Check this, for a start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20147921/actionbaractivity-getsupportactionbar-hide-throws-nullpointerexception. Also, try to change your application theme to android:Theme.Holo.Light instead.

Comment: And what about your Styles.xml file in values-v11 and values v-14? You have to set an AppCompat Theme there also.

Comment: Also check this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Adding. Hope it helps :D

Comment: Ahh No Friend , i think i need deep breath and will start from the beginning. I think Inside tabhost the loaded Activity not manage to find any Actionbar from the Parent Activity , that's why it's giving NullPointerException .....

Comment: The loaded Activity has its own ActionBar. Does not need to get it from the Parent Activity. THe problem must be different.

Comment: So i want to Hide the Parent Activity ActionBar from the Tabhost activity , so how i can do it ?

Comment: Yes but how can i hide it's ActionBar from Home.java while doing upside scrolling....

Comment: For that, you may take a different approach. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559275/hiding-the-actionbar-on-listview-scroll. It is exactly what you want.

Comment: Oh!! Friend that i know properly , if the scrolling code will in a tabhost then how can i hide the ActionBar of Parent Activity? Normally In the scrolling Up or Down the actionbar got hide but while i am doing from TabHost it showing an NullPointerException ....

Comment: It may be a bug in ActionBarImplICS class. mActionBar value is null. Hiding it or showing it returns null. You may also consider that TabActivity is deprecated. Its use is not recommended.