# Android - App crashes, using Swipe Tab Views

Tags: android, tabs, tabview

I have looked at every tutorial on the Internet about swipeable tab views with Android. Every time I use a different code, it crashes! The logcat gives this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual      
     method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setNavigationMode(int)' on a null 
     object reference
```

I have no idea why this does not work. Here is my MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private ActionBar actionBar;
private TabsPagerAdapter tabPagerAdapter;
private String[] tabs = {"Missed Calls", "Dialled", "Received"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    tabPagerAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(tabPagerAdapter);

    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        /**
         * on swipe select the respective tab
         * */
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}
```

Comment: What app theme you are using?

Comment: I am using Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Comment: This seems similar to this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23845738/why-getactionbar-getting-null-value-in-tabhost-from-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are getting null value of actionBar here:

```
actionBar = getActionBar(); 
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

change to

```
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

using the import:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

and remember, you have to extend from `ActionBarActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
```

More info:

> If you are using the support library
>
> `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;`
>
> `public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {`
>
> use
> `getSupportActionBar()`
> instead of `getActionBar()`